# Rules on encapsulating additional information:  use commas(,.... ,)or dashes (- ... -)?

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parentheses vs. double commas vs. dashes to provide additional detail](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4522/parentheses-vs-double-commas-vs-dashes-to-provide-additional-detail)

Here is the sentence where i struggled to find the grammatically correct  form:

> Just curious – what did you think of Mila **,** as a woman and as a person **,** when you met her?

and

> Just curious, what did you think of Jessica **--** as a woman and as a person **--** when you met her?

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: @RegDwight I think this question is more about what to do when there is more than one encapsulation in a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

'*As a woman and a person*' is a weak interruption and so should be set off by [commas](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node13.html#SECTION00044000000000000000), not [dashes](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node25.html#SECTION00072000000000000000). It's normal to use a comma to separate '*just curious*', but in this case that would be ugly, so I would use a semi-colon instead:

> Just curious; what did you think of
>   Jessica, as a woman and as a person,
>   when you met her?

Use of the semi-colon is [not entirely standard](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node17.html#SECTION00052000000000000000), but it's also [not unheard of](http://newavessays.com/tutorials/advanced-writing-tips/dialogues-punctuation/), since '*just curious*' pretty must stands alone as an utterance.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, and setting aside the specific case of "just curious" here for a moment, I think both formations are valid.  The important thing is to not use the same indicator in confusing ways within the same sentence.  So, for example, don't write "just curious -- what did you think of Jesica -- as a woman and as a person -- (etc)", because the use of unpaired and paired dashes in such close proximity is likely to be confusing.

I balked at "just curious" in the previous paragraph, because its use as a sentence fragment throws things off a bit.  I wouldn't use that construct in formal writing, though I might instead use "I'm just curious".  But if I did that, I would follow it with either a colon ("I'm curious about the following thing") or a dash; a comma would be too weak.

But if, instead of "just curious" you led with "therefore" or "however", I think either of your two constructs would be fine.