# dash to connect two thoughts

Tags: dashes

How can I use a dash to correctly connect two *and* thoughts in a sentence? Is the following sentence correct with the dash in *from* or should I remove it?

> An S database allows access from – and can be opened by multiple applications at the same time.

I am not familiar with the English grammar jargon and don't know how to properly call what I am attempting to do with that dash.

Although I still want to learn about the dash, would the following alternative sentence be correct?

> An S database allows access from, and can be opened by, multiple applications at the same time.

Comment: That depends – are you trying to [grab the reader by the throat](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105665/when-to-choose-em-dash-over-parenthesis-for-parenthetical-phrases/105667#105667)?

Comment: Message received, go easy on the dashes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example is the correct way to express the concepts in your sentences using commas.

The use of dashes would not be appropriate in these circumstances.  You mention joining *and* thoughts. The connection of equally weighted concepts is not usually joined with dashes, and if punctuation is needed, it is usually commas or semicolons.

Dashes are usually used within a sentence to indicate a side thought, often called a parenthetical phrase, because it could also be put inside of parentheses. An example would be

> An S database - the most versatile of storage systems - allows access from,and can be opened by, multiple applications at the same time.

The commas are needed in your sentence because the verb phrases *allows access from* and *can be opened by* use different prepositions.  If there were no prepositions, you could use *and* without the commas, such as

> An S database can access and open multiple applications at the same time

Comment: An S database allows access from, and can be opened by, multiple applications at the same time. An S database allows access from - and can be opened by - multiple applications at the same time. An S database allows access from (and can be opened by) multiple applications at the same time. The term _parenthesis_ is used for the syntactically non-essential insert in **each** of these equally grammatical variants (http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/parethesis_choice_of_parentheses.htm) .

Comment: The different degrees of emphasis are discussed at http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/dashes-parentheses-and-commas?page=all .

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, you can use a dash there but would need a dash after 'by' also.  It technically should be an 'em' dash, which is usually two dashes in a row.

You can also use commas, which I am now seeing you've updated your question to reflect, as I type this.

Comment: I think I've seen the use of a single dash along these lines, although I cannot remember where. I'll use the commas instead if it is correct. Would the sentence be correct without the commas and without the dash?

Comment: Some word processors will format am em dash as one long dash, Word for example.  You need some form of punctuation; otherwise the sentence will be ambiguous at best, but pretty much wrong.