# Using ' – ' in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Please suggest some alternatives as well.

Is this use of '–' OK?

"In 2006, when I was fourteen – early technological period for us – I got to see how a computer looked like, till that moment I had only heard rumor about computer."

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Parentheses-like_use for this kind of use of the em dash

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105665/when-to-choose-em-dash-over-parenthesis-for-parenthetical-phrases/) (if not a duplicate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> " In 2006, when I was fourteen -early technological period for us- I got to see how a computer looked like, till that moment I had only heard rumor about computer."

Is fine.  It means the same as

> " In 2006, when I was fourteen (early technological period for us) I got to see how a computer looked like, till that moment I had only heard rumor about computer."

BTW, try replacing `how` with `what`