# Should I use comma after i.e. clause?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> Automatic translation of classes to relations requires every regular, i.e. non-subclass and non-association classes to have a primary key.

> Automatic translation of classes to relations requires every regular, i.e. non-subclass and non-association classes, to have a primary key.

Which of the above is correct?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is not a proofreading service, but we can answer specific questions you have if you explain *why* you think a comma may or may not be appropriate, and what research you have done on the matter. The [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) will provide additional guidance on how to use this site.

Comment: That sentence doesn't make much sense, with or without the comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second sentence is not incorrect.  The first is grammatically incorrect.

However since the *i.e.* clause is an interruption for clarification one might argue that ideally it would be delineated with dashes, not commas.  E.g., see [Parentheses vs. double commas vs. dashes to provide additional detail](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4522/parentheses-vs-double-commas-vs-dashes-to-provide-additional-detail).