# Can em dashes be used to isolate clauses starting with an “or”?

Tags: clauses, dashes, comma-splices, interrupting-phrase

Here’s a simplified version of the sentence I'm working on.

> Despite what he believed — or thought he believed — he still had to
>   contend with the truth.

Or should I use commas?

Comment: Ugh. I don't think those spaces should be surrounding your em dashes. http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/091502enem.htm

Comment: I had a feeling something was wrong about the formatting. I won't use spaces. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no rule that prohibits the use of *or* to isolate clauses in your [*interrupting phrase*](http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/interphraseterm.htm):

> A word group (a statement, question, or exclamation) that interrupts the flow of a sentence and is usually set off by **commas, dashes, or parentheses**.

Note: there are rules for  using [dashes, parentheses, and commas](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/dashes-parentheses-and-commas?page=all).  See [parentheses vs. double commas vs. dashes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4522/parentheses-vs-double-commas-vs-dashes-to-provide-additional-detail) for additional details.