# Properly Using Hyphenated Clauses

Tags: hyphenation

I'm writing a paper about quantum computing and I'm trying to cite a source; however, I feel that the sentence in which I do this is clunky and forced.

> According to The Washington Post’s Vivek Wadhwa, these quantum
>   computers are capable of making computations that would take a binary machine years to perform in mere seconds.

I'm trying to divide the "that would take a binary machine years to perform" from the "in mere seconds." Would a hyphenated clause, such as the one below, be a proper solution?

> According to The Washington Post’s Vivek Wadhwa, these quantum
>   computers are capable of making computations -- ones that would’ve
>   taken a binary machine years to perform -- in mere seconds.

Comment: Comma is your friend.  "According to The Washington Post’s Vivek Wadhwa, these quantum computers are capable of performing, in mere seconds, computations that would take a binary machine years to perform."

Comment: (Which is why I still say that we never should have abandoned decimal computers.  And centessimal ones would be even better, no?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parentheses vs. double commas vs. dashes to provide additional detail](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4522/parentheses-vs-double-commas-vs-dashes-to-provide-additional-detail)

Comment: @HotLicks We should have stuck to tally marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

According to The Washington Post’s Vivek Wadhwa, these quantum computers are capable of making, in mere seconds, computations that would’ve taken a binary machine years to perform.