# Punctuation question: for the first time

Tags: punctuation

I am unsure how to punctuate the following sentence correctly. I want to stress that previous algorithms have not taken into account environmental conditions.

- We present an algorithm that, for the first time, considers enviromental conditions.
- We present an algorithm that - for the first time - considers enviromental conditions.
- We present an algorithm that considers enviromental conditions for the first time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parentheses vs. double commas vs. dashes to provide additional detail](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4522/parentheses-vs-double-commas-vs-dashes-to-provide-additional-detail). I'd add that the second variant needs dashes rather than the shorter hyphens, that all three variants are acceptable, and that the temporal adjunct is given greater emphasis in (1) and even greater emphasis in (2) (which is probably what you want). (3) sounds perhaps a little understated.

Comment: They are all 'correct', but you might consider rewording it: 'We present the first algorithm ever to consider environmental conditions.'